# Display text on screen independent of running screen

Tags: android, widget

I want to create an app that would display some text on screen independent of what app is running behind. Like in Settings--> Developers options --> show CPU usage. I am not understanding what should I search for this. Please guide me.

Comment: sounds interesting :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You needs an app using the system overlay permission.
See 
[Creating a system overlay window (always on top)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481226/creating-a-system-overlay-window-always-on-top) for an example.

Comment: hello. Its displaying an overlay. but the background clicks are not working.